# Mysqldump question

Tags: mysql

I am trying to dump a large database using mysqldump command. I would like to avoid 'use database' command in the generated sql file.
This is because I want to create the same database with a different name. Since the sql file size is large I am unable to open the sql file and edit it.

I tried --no-create-db but still I am getting use command in the dump file

Please help.

Answer (score 9):

Maybe you used something like this:

`mysqldump -u -p <other options> --database your_database > file.sql`

I discovered that when you use `--database`, the script is generated with that 'use your_database' line. So, don't use that option and the line is gone:

```
mysql -u -p <other options> your_database > file.sql
```

Answer (score 1):

You should maybe post this on serverfault, but if you are on a linux box, you could consider sed (or perl/python scripts) to replace the name of the database, or remove the "use " line.

Answer (score 1):

The way to do this is to run mysqldump once for each database. They way I did it is `mysqldump -u user -p --tables databasename`. This dumps all the tables for a database and removes the `USE` database statement.

Answer (score 0):

--no-create-db is your friend:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_no-create-db

Comment: I tried --no-create-db but still I am getting use comand in the dump file.

Comment: right, then just use sed to replace:

sed -i 's/use old_db_name/use new_db_name/' db_dump.sql